# php strpos offset outputs different

Tags: php

**What** is it that causes this **difference**?

```
echo strpos('abcdef abcdef', 'a', 0); //output= 0
echo strpos('abcdef abcdef', 'a', 1); //output= 7
echo strpos('a b- c a b* c a b+ c', 'c', 0); //output= 5 
echo strpos('a b- c a b* c a b+ c', 'c', 1); //output= 5 (But why? Is is must be 12)
echo strpos('a b- c a b* c a b+ c', 'c', 6); //output= 12
```

Comment: The first `c` in the string after offset `1` (the space between the first `a` and `b`) is still at offset `5`, it hasn't changed from the example using offset `0`; why do you think it should skip the `c` at offset `5` and pick the `c` at offset `12` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [3rd argument](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-parameters) is the starting location, not the number of found characters to skip. e.g.

```
strpos('...', 'a', 0)   option #1
strpos('...', 'a', 1)   option #2

abcdef abcdef
0123456789111
↑↑        012
││
└┼─ option #1: start at position 0('a'), and boom, find an 'a'
 └─ option #2; start at position 1('b'), find 'a' at position 7
```

So for your `a b- c a b* c a b+ c` string, the second version only skips **1** character, leaving the first `c` to be found at position 5:

```
a b- c a b* c a b+ c
01234567891111111111
↑↑    ↑   0123456789
││    │
└┼────┼─ start at position 0, first C at position 5
 └────┼─ start at position 1, first C still at 5
      └─ start at position 6, first C now at 12
```

Comment: @MarcB ascii art upgrade to unicode ;) (If you want to use them yourself: [Box drawing characters from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) and [the unicode arrows](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html))

Answer (score 1):

you use search offset 1 (start search one character from left) and therefore the first c is on position 5

```
mixed strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

Find the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the haystack string.

**offset**
If specified, search will start this number of characters counted from the beginning of the string. Unlike strrpos() and strripos(), the offset cannot be negative.

```
echo strpos('a b- c a b* c a b+ c', 'c', 1); //output= 5 (But why? Is is must be 12)

             0123456789111
              ^        012
              | your offset (start search 'c')
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php